# Can I say down north as well as down south?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Here are two definitions of the word "down" from TFD.com:

Down a.
Toward or in the south; southward: flew down to Florida.

**Down **b.****
In a particular part of a country: down south.

**According to definition b.**, can I say "I'm down north right now" (down meaning a particular part of a country which is north)?

Comment: Definitely "up north" instead.

Comment: @myacron What about “left East”?

Comment: In the US, California is sometimes referred to as "the left coast" but that's more about politics. Left as in politically left as in socialist.

Comment: Working-class people in London say (or used to say) 'I'm going up West' when they meant that they were going to the West End for entertainment or shopping. I noticed as a kid that the characters in the BBC comedy 'Steptoe and Son' said it even though their location was supposed to be Shepherd's Bush, so that they would be going east.

Comment: You could say "I'm down [North Downs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Downs) right now" :P

Comment: FYI, I see no such definition in [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/down), [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/down) or [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/down). Cambridge has a definition which just straight-up says "in or towards the south" (which doesn't seem to make that much sense when "down south" is the example, but does make it clear that "south" is the only valid option). I do find the definition you have there to be rather questionable.

Comment: @NotThatGuy There's "downtown" (and "uptown"), but it's a single word in modern usage.

Comment: @user09827 I've seen, and would use, "out" used for both East and West. "I'm headed out west for a couple weeks", etc. Although as mentioned in other comments, "back east" might be more colloquial.

Comment: What about in Australia or South America?

Comment: No, "down north" would never work. Let's just be clear about that.

Comment: @Neil - Even in the Southern hemisphere,"Up North" would still apply, as people below the equator do not look at their maps upside down.

Comment: @Michael Harvey Related to this is an extensive discussion [on EL & U](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/147832/why-do-americans-go-downtown-whilst-people-in-the-uk-go-up-town) about the use of up and down with regard to cities etc. It is a complex discussion and involves difference between US and British treatment.

Comment: **Technically,** you **can** say it (after all, God's not going to gag you...), but it should be quite apparent that north is "up", and so "down north" is a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

No, it is not idiomatic to say "down North".

It should be "up North".  The metaphor comes from the usual orientation of maps. "I flew up to Maine", for example.  The word "down" is only used with areas of the country that are southerly.

We don't really have anything similar for East or West.  Perhaps "out West" or "out East" would work.  "I flew out to Oregon" seems reasonable.

"Up North" and "down South" also work in Britain.

Comment: I don't know what *other* prepositions might occur with East and West, but... [*On Bay Street directly **across to the east** are the offices of Bell Canada.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22across+to+the+east+are%22) Facetiously in the UK it's ***Oop North*** rather than ***Up North***, reflecting the more common northern dialects (cf ***Darn Sarf*** reflecting London / Cockney speech).

Comment: Just in case someone is wondering, **far west** and **far east** are also good alternatives to "out west/east".

Comment: However "The Far East" refers to China, Korea, Japan  (countries that are located to the West of the USA...)

Comment: James I know that the word "up" and "down" stem from the orientation of maps, but what I was asking for was not that definition, but the second one( Maybe it's my fault, I edited the post and made it more legible), which states that the word "down" means "in a particular part of a country" In the first defitnition corresponding to the orientation of the maps the word  "up" is a synonyms for the word "north" , but in the second example it's not. You can see that by the fact that the sample sentence in the second def is "down south" which would mean "south south" which would be a  tautology.

Comment: Def b states: "in a particular part of a country" and south is only one of those parts. Therefore i believe you can use down for other parts of the country other than down and "down south" could be just a bad exaple chosen for that definition becouse it introduces alot of confusion associated with the fact that the word "down" also means "south" I hope i make myself clear.

Comment: You believe wrongly, you can only use "down" in this context with areas that are southerly.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A I’m one of them wondering.

Comment: I'm also a little confused about the definition b. becouse i always knew "up" and "down" to be associated with "north" and "south" and would find nothing wrong with a sentence "I'm going up north or down south" but the difinition in the TFD got me wondering. Do you guys think, this is just an error on their part and the definition b. is wrong?

Comment: Wiktionary has "South" or  "away from the city" (but downtown is the city center) or Towards a place that is visualised as lower due to local features, local topography, local convention or arbitrarily.  (slightly paraphrased).   Conventionally "down north" is never used.

Comment: I don't think anyone on this forum is able to answer this question. Or you guys can and the definition is simply wrong. That's the only possibilities there are. Can anyone give any example-sentence with the b. definition of the word "down" meaning "in a particular part of a country" other than "down south"?  or explain what i don't understand about that definintion because for me "in a particular part of a country" comprises more places and directions that solely "south"

Comment: In old-fashioned British usage 'up' was also used for 'towards London' or 'towards Oxford/Cambridge (universities)', so a 'down train' was one that took you away from the place in question.

Comment: "I'm going down to the park". "I'm down at the station waiting for a train. "  (Where local convention considers "the park" and "the station" to be "down"

Comment: Anyway,  Your question is answered.   Your question **is** "Can I say "I'm down north right now"?" and the answer is **No**.

Comment: @KateBunting - railway enthusiast here - in UK railway usage, 'up' _usually_ means 'towards London' and 'down' _usually_ means 'away from London' but it means 'towards/away from' some place regarded as primary or central by the railway. In most of Scotland, "up" is towards Edinburgh. The Valley Lines around Cardiff have their own peculiar usage, relating to the literal meaning of traveling "up" and "down" the valley. On the former Midland Railway "up" is still towards Derby. Trains from London to Cambridge are 'down trains'. Mostly the original 19th century designations are used still.

Comment: @KateBunting - I am reminded of the alleged utterance by Doctor Spooner to a student he was expelling from Oxford University - "You will leave by the town drain". I used to wonder if the student lived in Banbury or Worcester.

Comment: In Maine we say "down East" but that's because for sailors, the east is *down*wind and *down*current.  And even so, people think it's an odd usage.

Comment: The American phrase is "back East"

Comment: There is the construction "down [place] way".  Examples: [Down Vermont Way](https://kchistory.org/image/down-montgomery-way-vermont-0), [Down Argentine Way](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0032410/), and [Down Missouri Way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Down_Missouri_Way).  Even, "[down our way](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/down-sb-s-way)"

Comment: Re: "Perhaps 'out West' or 'out East' would work": I agree about "out west", but if you're talking about U.S. English then it's normally "*back* east" rather than "*out* east": https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=out+west%2Cout+east%2Cback+west%2Cback+east&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true

Comment: @ruakh "out East" certainly feels familiar, "out West" perhaps less so. The difference in my perception may come from their use in crossword clues to mean deleting an E or W, with E being moire common.

Comment: As an American I would say "Up North", "Down South", "Out West", and "Back East"

Comment: @MichaelHarvey In the US, trains usually use "in" and "out" to refer to to and from the hub city, respectively.

Comment: @Barmar in France, trains and tracks are 'pair' (even) towards Paris and 'impair' (odd) away from Paris.

Comment: Now I wonder if Russian has an "out East" equivalent...

Comment: @StaticBounce I could see possibly using "down TO" to indicate a particular part of the country, but then it wouldn't be used with a more general term like "north"; "down to Some City" or "down to That Region" could work for places not necessarily south of the speaker (although more common with southern regions). But "down north" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Agree that "down" could only really be used with the cardinal direction "south", but also that it can connote a level of importance or urban-ness. "I have to go down to city hall," for example, sounds totally natural to me regardless of what direction it's in.

Comment: I've heard "out west" from Australians as well - not sure about "back east".  Guessing since their population is similarly distributed to the US - most people on the east coast, some on the west, much fewer in the middle, it makes sense the terms would carry over.

Comment: For the US, I'd speculate that Out West references the westward migration of the (white) population during, say, the 1800s. Back East refers to where they came from. "He moved his family Out West." "I just sent a letter to my Ma, Back East."

Comment: @MikeA. a quite reasonable speculation (especially since it was the first thing I thought of...)

Answer (score 22):

Others have answered the (im)possibility of using "down north", but I think there is also a misconception on how to interpret dictionary entries based on your question and comments.

A dictionary entry records a word with its possible definition or definitions. However, it is most often not a complete description of the word's usage.

If a dictionary says word A has a meaning B, it means that the word A can mean B in certain contexts. It does not mean you can use A in its B sense in every context.

> **Down** b. in a particular part of a country: *down south*.

This means that *down* can mean "in a particular part of country", for example, in the phrase "down south" = "in the southern part of a country/geographical area". However, you cannot use the word *down* whenever "in a particular part of a country" is intended. The entry is only a description of the word's meaning in some situations; even if *down* can only mean "in a particular part of country" in the phrase *down south*, the entry is still valid.

For example, *dry* in "dry wine" means "not sweet", but if you cannot describe a savoury pancake as dry just because it is not sweet.

Comment: "If a dictionary says word A has a meaning B, it means that the word A can mean B in certain contexts. It does not mean you can use A in its B sense in every context." I'm a little confused now, actually... do *other* languages *not* work this way?

Comment: On the weekend I travelled 3 hours *North* to see family. They said "thanks for coming down to see us" and it sounded really strange. Given the context (we travelled South to North), "thanks for coming *up* to see us" would have made more sense. However, if someone had travelled from North to South to the same destination then "...coming *down* to see us" would have been fine. Context is key.

Comment: @ThomasClayson I've heard, or possibly made, comments like that inadvertently ;) It doesn't sound right but it also tends not to be worth correcting in conversation.

Comment: @ThomasClayson As mentioned in Kate Bunting's comments to the other answer, in the UK traditionally "down" can be used for "away from London/Oxford/Cambridge", so if you were travelling North out of London then "coming down to see us" fits the usage.

Comment: I haven't specifically checked for this in the past, but I'm under the impression that dictionaries typically qualify which contexts words can be used in (to a reasonable extent). Having a dictionary say only "in a particular part of a country" when the only valid part of that country is "south" seems unusual, to say the least. I find it telling that Cambridge Dictionary, Merriam-Webster and Dictionary.com all seem to opt for definitions explicitly mentioning the southerly direction instead. As for "dry" meaning "not sweet", the definitions I checked explicitly mention alcoholic drinks.

Comment: @NotThatGuy Consider the scenario where one lives at higher altitude and travels "down to the lowlands" while traveling north.  The "lowlands" would be a particular part of that country which may not be south of where one presently is.  Consider also the term "downtown"--is that only southward?

Answer (score 13):

As mentioned in [this answer on English.SX,](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140290/do-australians-say-down-north) sometimes people say “down North” in places where the rivers run downhill to the north, such as arctic Canada.  Examples include the book title, *Down North to the Sea: 2,000 Miles by Canoe to the Arctic Ocean*. “Down North” is also sometimes used as a proper name, including for a region of Ireland.

Nearly all the examples I found use “down north” in the literal sense that the destination is lower in elevation.  It would not surprise me if people somewhere use it in a metaphorical sense.  I could imagine someone saying “down north” as a shorthand for “downtown, in the city north of here,” or some stuck-up person going “down” to the bad north side of town.

Comment: This is special usage and not usually seen.

Comment: "Down East" is a directional phrase used in Maine because of the shape of the coast, as I understand it. Wikipedia says "an area that closely corresponds to the historical French territory of Acadia."

Comment: Naturally, Australia -- land of fire and killer *everything* -- has to be different.

Comment: @RonJohn Not seeing where Australia comes into this? People there definitely go "up north" to (tropical) Queensland and "down south" to (chilly) Tasmania.

Answer (score 8):

Definition b in this case is highly idiomatic. The example given, "down south," is the pairing that most English speakers would use most of the time. There are words other than *south* that could be used with this sense of *down*, but only in very localized circumstances.

For example, there is a part of the coast of the state of Maine in the U.S. that is known as ["down east"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Down_East) Maine.
But if you were in the western end of Massachusetts (a nearby state) and told people there that you were going "down east" to Boston (which is in the eastern end of Massachusetts), they would think this was a very strange thing to say.

There may be other examples of "down _____" that are applicable in other locales that I do not know about. But in almost all places where it makes any sense to put a compass direction in the blank space in that phrase, "south" is the only word that is suitable. The definition as stated seems to imply that "down south" is only one of several possible examples that might commonly be used, but this is misleading.

Answer (score 7):

As has already been said, the common phrases are *down South* and *up North*.

In England, owing to railway terminology, *up* and *down* can mean *towards London* and *away from London* respectively. So, even someone who is located north of London will say: "I'm going up to London".

For East and West, we often use *over* in statements like: "I'm going over to Ramsgate", (but **not** just *over East*).

Comment: Closest (of distressingly many) answers here to the answer I wanted to make, so you get an upvote. For those who don't like my answer for some reason, I'd say you should look at this one. It is essentially correct.

Comment: Same thing happens in Ireland. It's quite normal for someone to talk about going "up to Dublin" regardless of where they are coming from. Conversely, you can also talk about going "down to _any-provincial-town_".

Comment: This also happens in my home state where people in towns along a river valley tend to refer to going "down to <x town>" if it's downriver, and "up to <y town>" if it's upriver, in spite of being north and south respectively.  However nobody says "down north ..." or "up south", but specifically names the town.

Comment: You also go "up" to a university town, or are "sent down" if expelled; I believe there is also "going up to London". So I would suggest that while some usage is based on map orientation or river flow, almost all of it is cultural. I would remind readers of the infamous Spoonerism: "Sir, you have just tasted two whole worms ... you will depart on the next town drain" i.e. the train leaving Oxford was "down", irrespective of whether it was heading towards London or not, and as such usage probably predates the railways ("up train" and "down train" relative to the company's central station).

Answer (score 3):

The directions you hear in use in English are meant as map directions, relative to the middle of the map. When you hang a map on the wall, the standard is North is on the top (which puts South on the bottom, West on the left side, and East on the right side).

So, points far away relative to the center of the map (or perhaps to you conversationally) are "**Up** North", "**Down** South", or "Over in/to/at" for points East or West. This is to help those of us who visualize a mental map in our heads for finding our way about.

Comment: I would see no problem with "out west" or "back east"  but have never heard  "in west" or "at west" or "to west"

Comment: @Criggie - If you reread that sentence, you'll see I specifically didn't phrase it that way. I'd suggest looking Spiritman's answer for an example that uses the "to" construction.

Comment: out west and back east sound very American to my British ears (especially as they appear to be a reference to westward expansion)

Comment: I know that a question was "Can I say down north as well as down south?" and that it was answered, but the fact that I posted it stemed from the usage to be  unclear to me,  because of the example in the dictionary and lack of explanation in it about the limitations of that usage, that was eventually provided by xngtng here. So basically... I didn't know, what I didn't know, but know I know what I didn't know as well as I know it :) THX GUYS <BTW Jame's answer with the highest rating still by all means valid and appreciated :)>

Comment: @Tristan - I was thinking the exact same thing, but as an American didn't know if it really isn't said that way outside our shores. Its really funny how much social and historical context we pack into these silly little prepositions. Thanks for piping up.

Comment: no worries. I don't think we actually have any sort of equivalent for East/West. I was going to say that was because our country is more divided North/South and, whilst that is the case, the cultural divide across the Pennines (between the East and West halves of the North), and between the Southeast and the West Country is pretty signficant

Answer (score 3):

In many parts of the US, especially in hilly or mountainous regions, people often use up and down to correspond to difference in elevation regardless of compass direction.

For example, you could say, "I'm going down to the store," when the store is downhill and north of your current location.

Here's another common one: "We're going up on X drive," referring to a park located on top of a mountain.

Comment: It's the same in hilly parts of the UK. Trivial point of interest: In casual speech, 'up' and 'down' often _replace_ 'to', so we say "I'm going up the shop" (or down).

Answer (score 1):

All depends on where you are. There was a time when everything moved by sail, and the fastest and most reliable way to get anywhere was by going **down**wind. That's how we get going "Down East" for Maine, because east is downwind of the prevailing westerlies. But modern Maine has succumbed to conformity and today, to all but die-hard yankees and sailors, "Down East" means a popular magazine and not much else. However, in Cape Breton, every day locals still refer to going north as going down. Similarly, "below" means to the north (eg: Cheticamp is below or "down from" Inverness), and when something is "Lower" in a place name, or even generically as in "the lower settlement," it means north of someplace. It drives American tourists bonkers who are always getting lost, having interpreted the directions they were given in an upside down fashion.

Answer (score 0):

In Canada (from the Great Lakes to the east at least), saying "down east"  (as opposed to "out west") is common.

It's likely because the Great Lakes and the St. Lawrence River flow from west to east across half the country, so if you are in a boat going downstream, you're heading east.

I imagine "down north" or whatever it's equivalent was, would have been common in lands around the Nile River, which flows from south to north.